# jQuery Trigger Key Event Failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

The site I'm trying to userscript for requires an account to see where the issue is occurring.

https://www.recipal.com/log_in

yeti.floats@gmail.com

> StackOverflow1!

Then visit https://www.recipal.com/recipes/1698297/edit to see the input box in question. The script successfully inputs a value, the front-end reflects that the box is focused, but the anticipated result does not occur from simulating the keypress.

From comparing the console outputs of a simulated press and a real one, the only thing I can see that varies is the originalEvent attribute, which seemingly cannot be spoofed?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

jQuery code used to produce the input:

```
var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press.which = 13;
press.keyCode = 13;
press.charCode = 13;
press.key='Enter';
press.bubbles=true;

$('#search_field').attr('tabindex',1);
$('#search_field').focus().trigger('click').val("chicken");
setTimeout(()=>{

    $('#search_field').trigger(press).trigger('keyup');
},1000);
```

console output:

```
{
    "type": "keypress",
    "timeStamp": 1704464067050,
    "jQuery34105937047508940263": true,
    "which": 13,
    "keyCode": 13,
    "charCode": 13,
    "key": "Enter",
    "bubbles": true,
    "isTrigger": 3,
    "namespace": "",
    "rnamespace": null,
    "target": {
        "jQuery341059370475089402631": {
            "events": {
                "focus": [
                    {
                        "type": "focus",
                        "origType": "focus",
                        "guid": 118,
                        "namespace": false
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "focus",
                        "origType": "focus",
                        "guid": 117,
                        "namespace": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "focus": false
        }
    },
    "delegateTarget": {
        "location": {
            "ancestorOrigins": {},
            "href": "https://www.recipal.com/recipes/1230714/edit",
            "origin": "https://www.recipal.com",
            "protocol": "https:",
            "host": "www.recipal.com",
            "hostname": "www.recipal.com",
            "port": "",
            "pathname": "/recipes/1230714/edit",
            "search": "",
            "hash": ""
        },
        "jQuery341059370475089402631": {
            "events": {
                "mouseup": [
                    {
                        "type": "mouseup",
                        "origType": "mouseup",
                        "guid": 3,
                        "namespace": ""
                    }
                ],
                "change": [
                    {
                        "type": "change",
                        "origType": "change",
                        "guid": 5,
                        "selector": "#faSizeIngred",
                        "needsContext": false,
                        "namespace": ""
                    }
                ],
                "keypress": [
                    {
                        "type": "keypress",
                        "origType": "keypress",
                        "guid": 6,
                        "selector": "#search_field",
                        "needsContext": false,
                        "namespace": ""
                    }
                ],
                "focusin": [
                    {
                        "type": "focusin",
                        "origType": "focus",
                        "guid": 7,
                        "selector": "#search_field",
                        "needsContext": false,
                        "namespace": ""
                    }
                ],
                "click": [
                    {
                        "type": "click",
                        "origType": "click",
                        "guid": 8,
                        "selector": ".btn-addtorecipe:not(.btn-mini)",
                        "needsContext": false,
                        "namespace": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "click",
                        "origType": "click",
                        "guid": 10,
                        "selector": "#pushMacs",
                        "needsContext": false,
                        "namespace": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "click",
                        "origType": "click",
                        "guid": 30,
                        "namespace": "menu1"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "click",
                        "origType": "click",
                        "guid": 54,
                        "namespace": "menu3"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "click",
                        "origType": "click",
                        "guid": 78,
                        "namespace": "menu5"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "click",
                        "origType": "click",
                        "guid": 102,
                        "namespace": "menu7"
                    }
                ],
                "keyup": [
                    {
                        "type": "keyup",
                        "origType": "keyup",
                        "guid": 9,
                        "selector": "#faAggredName",
                        "needsContext": false,
                        "namespace": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "focusin": 1
        }
    },
    "currentTarget": {
        "jQuery341059370475089402631": {
            "events": {
                "focus": [
                    {
                        "type": "focus",
                        "origType": "focus",
                        "guid": 118,
                        "namespace": false
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "focus",
                        "origType": "focus",
                        "guid": 117,
                        "namespace": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "focus": false
        }
    },
    "handleObj": {
        "type": "keypress",
        "origType": "keypress",
        "guid": 6,
        "selector": "#search_field",
        "needsContext": false,
        "namespace": ""
    }
}
```

Human input event data:

```
{
    "originalEvent": {
        "isTrusted": true
    },
    "type": "keypress",
    "target": {
        "jQuery341059370475089402631": {
            "events": {
                "focus": [
                    {
                        "type": "focus",
                        "origType": "focus",
                        "guid": 118,
                        "namespace": false
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "focus",
                        "origType": "focus",
                        "guid": 117,
                        "namespace": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "focus": false
        }
    },
    "currentTarget": {
        "jQuery341059370475089402631": {
            "events": {
                "focus": [
                    {
                        "type": "focus",
                        "origType": "focus",
                        "guid": 118,
                        "namespace": false
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "focus",
                        "origType": "focus",
                        "guid": 117,
                        "namespace": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "focus": false
        }
    },
    "timeStamp": 24011519.5,
    "jQuery34105937047508940263": true,
    "delegateTarget": {
        "location": {
            "ancestorOrigins": {},
            "href": "https://www.recipal.com/recipes/1230714/edit",
            "origin": "https://www.recipal.com",
            "protocol": "https:",
            "host": "www.recipal.com",
            "hostname": "www.recipal.com",
            "port": "",
            "pathname": "/recipes/1230714/edit",
            "search": "",
            "hash": ""
        },
        "jQuery341059370475089402631": {
            "events": {
                "mouseup": [
                    {
                        "type": "mouseup",
                        "origType": "mouseup",
                        "guid": 3,
                        "namespace": ""
                    }
                ],
                "change": [
                    {
                        "type": "change",
                        "origType": "change",
                        "guid": 5,
                        "selector": "#faSizeIngred",
                        "needsContext": false,
                        "namespace": ""
                    }
                ],
                "keypress": [
                    {
                        "type": "keypress",
                        "origType": "keypress",
                        "guid": 6,
                        "selector": "#search_field",
                        "needsContext": false,
                        "namespace": ""
                    }
                ],
                "focusin": [
                    {
                        "type": "focusin",
                        "origType": "focus",
                        "guid": 7,
                        "selector": "#search_field",
                        "needsContext": false,
                        "namespace": ""
                    }
                ],
                "click": [
                    {
                        "type": "click",
                        "origType": "click",
                        "guid": 8,
                        "selector": ".btn-addtorecipe:not(.btn-mini)",
                        "needsContext": false,
                        "namespace": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "click",
                        "origType": "click",
                        "guid": 10,
                        "selector": "#pushMacs",
                        "needsContext": false,
                        "namespace": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "click",
                        "origType": "click",
                        "guid": 30,
                        "namespace": "menu1"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "click",
                        "origType": "click",
                        "guid": 54,
                        "namespace": "menu3"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "click",
                        "origType": "click",
                        "guid": 78,
                        "namespace": "menu5"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "click",
                        "origType": "click",
                        "guid": 102,
                        "namespace": "menu7"
                    }
                ],
                "keyup": [
                    {
                        "type": "keyup",
                        "origType": "keyup",
                        "guid": 9,
                        "selector": "#faAggredName",
                        "needsContext": false,
                        "namespace": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "focusin": 1
        }
    },
    "handleObj": {
        "type": "keypress",
        "origType": "keypress",
        "guid": 6,
        "selector": "#search_field",
        "needsContext": false,
        "namespace": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your goal...
What is the purpose of `$('#search_field').focus().trigger('click').val("chicken")` ?

Comment: Hi @Pof - That is the line that inserts a value in the search box. Focus to ensure it is operable, trigger click I threw in based on another S/O question I read, didn't help, but figured no good reason to remove it.

Chicken is just a random search term which would return results in their search. In the actual script, the "chicken" value would be a variable value. The script iterates over saved recipes in my own database to rebuild them on ReciPal, in case we ever want to modify an existing recipe, we don't have to manually rebuild them.

Comment: Better do a simple `$('#search_field').val("chicken")` to change value of input

Comment: Hey @Pof - that's not the issue. The value is being inserted. The problem is that the next line (wrapped in a setTimeout) is not executing. In order for the search box to return results, an Enter keystroke must be used, and the input box is not accepting that programmatic input.

Comment: Better do a submit on your form `$('#search-form').trigger("submit")`.
Pressing the "enter" button on a form is triggering a form submit

Comment: @Pof The result of that is I wind up at an error page with a query string of the form values, rather than whatever javascript ajax call is occurring with a user input enter keystroke

Comment: The search seems to be triggered on input change. Did you tried `$('#search_field').trigger('change')` to trigger the search ?

Comment: @Pof No change - the responses do not appear after triggering change

Comment: How did you code the search triggering ? I mean the panel which is showing under the search bar ? What does trigger it ?

Comment: Any keystroke seems to trigger it from human input, @Pof. That's why I was trying to use the enter keystroke, because once the total value is input what else is there to type?

Comment: If you code your form yourself, maybe it could be better to trigger the function that do the search ? Then no need to do some trigger('keypress') trick ?

Comment: I'm sorry are you asking if I developed Recipal? @Pof